# Conexão SQL com PHP não acha os Drivers

Tags: php, sql

Tenho o seguinte PHP:

```
<?php

class Conexao
{
   private static $connection;

   private function __construct(){}

   public static function getConnection() {

       $pdoConfig  = DB_DRIVER . ":". "Server=" . DB_HOST . ";";
       $pdoConfig .= "Database=".DB_NAME.";";

       try {
           if(!isset($connection)){
               $connection =  new PDO($pdoConfig, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
               $connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
           }
           return $connection;
       } catch (PDOException $e) {
           $mensagem = "Drivers disponiveis: " . implode(",", PDO::getAvailableDrivers());
           $mensagem .= "\nErro: " . $e->getMessage();
           throw new Exception($mensagem);
       }
   }
}
   define('DB_HOST'        , "dblinx");
   define('DB_USER'        , "maicon.friedel");
   define('DB_PASSWORD'    , "Mf2681");
   define('DB_NAME'        , "Linx");
   define('DB_DRIVER'      , "sqlsrv");

   try{

       $Conexao    = Conexao::getConnection();
       $query      = $Conexao->query("SELECT nome, preco, quantidade FROM produto");
       $produtos   = $query->fetchAll();

   }catch(Exception $e){
       echo $e->getMessage();
       exit;
   }

?>
<table border=1>
   <tr>
       <td>Nome</td>
       <td>Preço</td>
       <td>Quantidade</td>
   </tr>
   <?php
       foreach($produtos as $produto) {
   ?>
       <tr>
           <td><?php echo $produto['nome']; ?></td>
           <td>R$ <?php echo $produto['preco']; ?></td>
           <td><?php echo $produto['quantidade']; ?></td>
       </tr>
   <?php
       }
   ?>
</table>
```

Porém, sempre aparece isso:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E, como podem ver, eu coloquei os drivers certos, versão 7.2 PHP, drivers da versão correta:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Está a usar alguma ferramenta como WAMP, pode partilhar mais alguma coisa do seu setup. por exemplo o seu php.ini

Comment: Adiconei os extensions no php.ini..

Comment: Você instalou os drivers ODBC https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/connect/php/system-requirements-for-the-php-sql-driver?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Sim, instalei os drivers ODBC e continua aparecendo a mesma mensagem

Comment: O seu PHP é x86 ou x64

Comment: x64.................

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bom vamos começar, você precisa:

Instalar um driver no seu pc, e no seu php, porem você ja instalou no php, correto?

Veja essa ODBC e instale: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55642

Caso tenha mais dúvidas pode olhar o https://www.dirceuresende.com/blog/como-conectar-no-sql-server-utilizando-o-php-xampp-e-o-driver-pdo-no-windows/

Comment: Cara... muuuuuuuuuito obrigado! Olhando esses dois tutoriais que você passou, funcionou! Muuuítissimo obrigado mesmo.

Answer (score 0):

O site da Microsoft explica o que é necessário para a conexão com o SQL Server.

Provavelmente está faltando você incluir as extensões em seu php.ini

O arquivo fica no mesmo caminho de suas dlls.

O passo a passo é para SQL Server 2017, porém é só adaptar a versão que está usando.

Segue referência para verificar o passo a passo:

https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/connect/php/loading-the-php-sql-driver?view=sql-server-2017